# In Matplotlib's imshow, can I enforce symmetric color limits without specifying the range?

Tags: matplotlib, colors

I would like to plot a difference image with symmetric color limits, without having to compute the color limits myself. That is, my image may have intensities in the range `[-3, 5]`. By default, `imshow` uses these value for the color limits, and with a diverging color map, the white center is at 1. The reason is that I might later change the image and would like to prevent having to recompute the color limits myself in every animation step.

Can I make `imshow` force to use centered color limits, in my example, `[-5, 5]`, without passing `[-5, 5]` myself?

Comment: I don't think I understand this. A colormapping needs some limits to know which color should be chosen for which value. So suppose the colorlimits of the first plot are [-5,5] (be it because you set it, or because it is set internally, doesn't matter). Now the next plot gets generated. What would be the desired limits for that one? Would it be [-5,5] because the first plot has those? Or would it be, let's say [-10,10] because that would make sense for the data? But if so, how could the first plot have known to use [-10,10]?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean you dont want to manually calculate the limits for each plot, but are OK with the limits being updated as you change the plot.

In this case, you need to calculate which of your limits is a higher absolute number and then pass its negative to `vmin` the number itself to `vmax` keywords in `imshow`. Here is a minimal example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.zeros((10, 10))
for i in range(10):
    data[i] = np.linspace(-3, 5, 10)

def plot(data):
    limit = max(abs(np.min(data)), abs(np.max(data)) )

    plt.imshow(data, aspect='auto', cmap='RdBu',
              vmin=-limit, vmax=limit)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, you are assuming correct: 1. I "dont want to manually calculate the limits for each plot", 2. I would like "limits being updated as I change the plot". But as far as I can see, your code does neither: 1. It manually calculates the limits. 2. It does not update the limits when data is changed (too see that, add `.set_array(10 * np.ones_like(data))` to the `imshow` line).

Comment: By the way, your example is missing `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np` to work.

Comment: @bers, I updated for the imports and turned the plotting into a function, which should work as you want, but maybe your question was whether this can be forced by some functionality in imshow? I dont think there is a way to do that, but maybe I am wrong

Comment: Yes, that was my question. I do not want to compute `limits`.